# A node() containing text() and children has to be transformed into uppercase-text

Tags: xml, nested, uppercase, xslt-3.0

This feels like something easy to achieve but I still grapple to get my head around:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div> 
<p><hi rend="capitals">Some <rs>text</rs> with <rs>bold</rs> content</hi></p>
<p><hi rend="capitals"><rs>Some text</rs> / <rs>with a slash</rs></hi></p>
</div>
```

I want to achieve this output via an transformation with XLST:

> SOME TEXT WITH BOLD CONTENT

> SOME TEXT / WITH A SLASH

The difficulty stems from the mixing of text() and rs. As there are some other things to be done with rs I have to do the conversions of text() and child nodes separately.

I have this XLST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:foo="whatever" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="rs">
        <xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:function name="foo:upperCase-recursion">
        <xsl:param name="node-selection" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:param name="mycounter" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="number-of-children" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case($node-selection/text()[$mycounter])"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$node-selection/child::*[$mycounter]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$mycounter &lt; $number-of-children">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="foo:upperCase-recursion($node-selection, $mycounter + 1, $number-of-children)"
                />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case($node-selection/text()[$mycounter + 1])"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="hi[@rend = 'capitals']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(child::*[1])">
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:upper-case(text())"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="number-of-children" select="count(child::*)" as="xs:integer"/>
                <xsl:variable name="mycounter" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="foo:upperCase-recursion(., $mycounter, $number-of-children)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output always puts the slash of the second row to the opening of the line:

> SOME TEXT WITH BOLD CONTENT

> / SOME TEXTWITH A SLASH

How can I fix this?

Comment: Now it dawns me that I'm counting only the child-nodes but not the text(). Still no clue how to fix it though

Comment: So the XML input is transformed to plain text where you want all upper case letters for the contents of `hi` elements with `rend` saying `capitals`? What are the exact difficulties? Any template `<xsl:template match="hi[@rend = 'capitals']//text()"><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/></xsl:template>` would achieve that. If any child elements need additional transformation rules you can do that with templates for the child elements.

Comment: You are right! I somehow figured I was approaching it too complex.